# Failed to install Docker on Debian Stretch

Tags: docker, debian

I'm following these instructions to install Docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

I've successfully created /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian   stretch stable
```

However, when I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error about not being able to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian oldstable InRelease
Hit:7 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:9 http://debian.mirror.iweb.ca/debian stretch Release
Ign:11 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: As error messages says: "Is the package apt-transport-https installed?"

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that error was related. I installed apt-transport-https and after this I was able to run `sudo apt-get update` with no errors and then install docker. Thank you!

Comment: [U&L: apt-get fails: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263801/apt-get-fails-the-method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-https-could-not-be-found)